# Dropdown list for time : hour and minutes separately on html and php

Tags: php, html

I created two dropdown list for manage time. First dropdown list to manage hour in 24 hours format (Office Time) is 08.00-21.00. The second dropdown list is minutes 00-59. I blank.

```
 <select id="Hour" class="input-small">
    <?php
       for ($i=8; $i<=21; $i++){
         echo "<option value='".$i."'>" . $i ."</option>";
       }
    ?>
 </select>

 :

 <select id="Minutes" class="input-small">
    <?php

        for ($i=0; $i<=59; $i++){
             echo "<option value='".$i."'>" . $i ."</option>";
      }
    ?>
 </select>
```

How to created this in php code ?

Sorry, the problem is in hour format  :
let see. if 01, it printed 1. So, if user wanna to insert 01.00, it failed because the result is: 1.0 . It gives me error when I insert to database.

Comment: I don't get the issue here this code should be working fine.

Comment: And what is the problem?

Comment: this code works flawlessly! what are you trying to ask here

Comment: Maybe a dumb question, but is PHP installed on the machine (example- are you running it off a windows desktop-saved file as opposed to in the WAMP folders)?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep format : 01,02, ... you can make a function in php after submitting form to add 0 before the value under 10. Like :

```
if($_POST['Hour'] < 10 ){
    $concat = "0".$_POST['hour'];
}
```

But it's not very clean.
You can use str_pad() : http://php.net/manual/fr/function.str-pad.php

(Thanks Raptor for the comment)

Comment: Ouch. Don't do that. While casting to `DateTime` is an overkill, `str_pad()` is an alternative way to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Your suggested format (08.00-21.00) is incompatible with database (well, I assume you're using MySQL). You didn't mention what is the data type of the column, but as in your case, you should be storing the information as `VARCHAR`.

To format the post values to your suggested format, you can use the following:

```
$open_time = str_pad($_POST['hour'], 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT) . '.' . str_pad($_POST['minute'], 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

p.s. you should give a name to your input `<select>`

Comment: Clarify: You can't put `08.00-21.00` in `TIME` format, `08.00` can't either. You should put something like `08:00`.